# Angular2 - Class constructor cannot be invoked without 'new'

Tags: javascript, angular, odata

I'm trying to integrate angular2-odata library. I'm using

```js
    @Injectable()
    class MyODataConfig extends ODataConfiguration{
        baseUrl="http://localhost:54872/odata/";
    }

    bootstrap(app,[
        //some of my other providers etc.
        provide(ODataConfiguration, {useClass:MyODataConfig}),
        ODataServiceFactory,
    ]
```

Problem is that when I try to inject ODataServiceFactory all I get is following error:

EXCEPTION: Error during instantiation of ODataConfiguration! (ClassService -> ODataServiceFactory -> ODataConfiguration).
ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: TypeError: Class constructor ODataConfiguration cannot be invoked without 'new'

I googled it and it seems that there is some problem while trying to inject extended class, but I was not able to find solution for this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I think your class needs a constructor that calls `super();`

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, but I tried to add  constructor() {
        super();
    } and the exception is same.

Comment: Could you post your `ODataServiceFactory` implementation as well?

Comment: You can look at ODataServiceFactory on github of angular2-odata library https://github.com/gallayl/angular2-odata/blob/master/odataservicefactory.ts

Answer (score 1):

A temporary workaround is to use new on the ODataConfiguration class and then override the **baseUrl** :

```
@Component({
    templateUrl: './categoryGridOData.component.html',
    selector: 'my-category-grid-odata',
    providers: [ { provide: ODataConfiguration, useFactory: () => {
        let odta = new ODataConfiguration();
        odta.baseUrl = 'http://services.odata.org/V4/Northwind/Northwind.svc';
        return odta; }
    }, ODataServiceFactory ],
    styleUrls: [ './carGrid.component.css']
})
export class CategoryGridODataComponent {
```

For complete code see : https://github.com/StefH/angular2-webpack-starter/blob/_stef_dev/src/app/car/categoryGridOData.component.ts#L18

For some more details see : https://github.com/gallayl/angular2-odata/issues/3